# Send Sanctum token automaticaly

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm working on a `Laravel 8` Project with Sanctum and `VueJs`, and I would like to know if there is any way to send the `token` without write each time header in my `axios` request:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        axios
            .get("/api/endpoint/", {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + token
                }
            })
            .then(response => (this.expenses = response.data));
    }
```

Comment: single page applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define axios config in lib or something like this:

```js
import Axios from 'axios'

const axios = Axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_BASE_URL,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token
    },
})

export default axios
```

Then use your lib instead of base axios like this:

```js
import axios from '@/lib/axios'

 axios.post(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use axios configs.

for example, import axios :

```
window.axios = require('axios');
```

then you can use this:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer ...";
```

you can store your token inside `localStorage` and use it here.

another way is to use axios interceptors.
you read the document about the interceptors [here](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors).